# WPF: how to make KeyBinding on a customcontrol work without focus

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, key-bindings, inputbinding

I have two custom controls. The first one consists of a textbox and a popup/dropdown. The other consist of a expander and some content inside the expander.

Most of the time, I will display the second control inside the popup of the first.

The second control should have a hotkey for toggling the expander.

How can I make a keybinding in the second control in such a way that it will work even if the focus is inside the textbox of the first control?

Comment: I think you cant, without some tricks.
Easiest way is create a property, bind it to Expander.IsExpanded property, and change it in your `Command`. But your `Command` should be `keybind`ed with the first control (or with it textbox).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Focus is always essential for KeyBindings to work... did u try setting the CommandTarget of the KeyBinding to your Expander control?

Something like below...

```
<KeyBinding Key="O" Modifiers="Control"
            Command="localns:ApplicationWindow.Open"
            CommandTarget="{x:Static localns:MyWindow.CustomControlInstance.Expander}" />
```

Let me know if this helps.